# Fetch an array from API endpoint in async function

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, async-await

I've been studying javascript for the love of it, I'm currently learning how to use async functions and my code actually works, but I know there is always room for improving.

I'm open to any help regarding my use of async functions and how I use the return of `sizeJokesArray()` in `fetchJokes()`.

```js
const jokeContainer = document.querySelector('.joke-container');

async function sizeJokesArray() {
  let url = 'https://api.icndb.com/jokes/count';
  let data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  return data.value;
}

async function fetchJokes() {
  let url = `https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/${length}`;
  let jokesData = [];
  let data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  for (jokePosition in data.value) {
    jokesData.push(data.value[jokePosition].joke);
  }
  return jokesData;
}

sizeJokesArray().then(size => (length = size)); // return of sizeJokesArray

jokeContainer.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.value === 'Fetch') {
    fetchJokes(length).then(jokesData => (jokesArray = jokesData)).then(jokesData => (console.log(jokesData)));
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="joke-container">
    <div class="joke-text">
        <p>Fetch some jokes bro!!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="joke-controls">
        <button type="button" value="Fetch">Fetch Jokes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

the existing `console.log()` it's not actually used in my code just used it here to log my results for the question purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've improved a few things to your script, making it more consistent over all:

```js
;(function () {
  const jokeContainer = document.querySelector('.joke-container')

  async function fetchCount() {
    const url = 'https://api.icndb.com/jokes/count'
    const { value } = await (await fetch(url)).json()

    return value
  }

  async function fetchJokes(length = fetchCount()) {
    const url = `https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/${await length}`
    const { value } = await (await fetch(url)).json()

    return value.map(({ joke }) => joke)
  }

  jokeContainer.addEventListener('click', async event => {
    if (event.target.value === 'Fetch') {
      const jokes = await fetchJokes()

      console.log(jokes)
    }
  })
}())
```

```html
<div class="joke-container">
  <div class="joke-text">
    <p>Fetch some jokes bro!!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="joke-controls">
    <button type="button" value="Fetch">Fetch Jokes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Wrapped your script in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to avoid polluting the global scope.
- Removed your bizarre usage of the global `length` variable, which you defined without using `var`, `let`, or `const`, and is considered bad practice.
- Used [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to improve the readability of your code in some places.
- Declared your event listener as `async` in order to take advantage of `await` instead of using a `then()` chain to improve consistency and readability.
- Converted your imperative initialization of `jokesData` into a functional idiomatic approach using [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in order to further improve readability.

Comment: is this `const { value } = await (await fetch(url)).json()` object destructuring or what is this doing? it blew my mind!

Comment: Yes, it's the same as `const value = (await (await fetch(url)).json()).value`

Comment: Learned more from your answer then like the past month studying and reading about `.then()`, `await`, `async` and such... Thanks now ill read about the last point you mentioned.

Comment: @ricardoNava it's called the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), but it's also used in the argument of the `Array#map()` callback in this answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can improve.

```
sizeJokesArray().then(size => (length = size)); // return of sizeJokesArray

jokeContainer.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.value === 'Fetch') {
    fetchJokes(length).then(jokesData => (jokesArray = jokesData)).then(jokesData => (console.log(jokesData)));
  }
});
```

You can change it to

```
let jokes = [];
jokeContainer.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.value === 'Fetch') {
    try {
         let length = await sizeJokesArray(); // You dont get ".then" here where you were assigning length variable, if you are using async/await. Use it properly, there is no use of an async function if you are calling it in promise fashion.
         jokes = await fetchJokes(length) // Isn't it easy and clean to read that jokes are meant to be fetch and we are waiting for it.
         console.log(jokes); 
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle API error here
    }
  }
});
```

When you use *async/await*, Use it properly everywhere.
instead of calling *then()* you should be awaiting it. also handle error via *try/catch*

Comment: so ... why is this an improvement? Elaborate just a tad here ;)

Comment: Why would I want to have my variables in the global scope?

Comment: and, using `let` in the global scope is kinda pointless

Comment: You dont want to use `var` because its more pointless. I am assuming that this function is within some module and not global.
also if you use `const` you cant change its reference, thus you have to stick with `var` in this scenario

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce using `let` in global scope is not pointless. Unlike the respective `var` declaration, the variable name is not accessible on the `window` object. So given a top-level `let foo = 'bar';`, `window.foo` does not exist.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - could you help me understand why that little quirk makes it not pointless? could you give me an example of how that would be useful? cus it still seems pretty pointless to me. using var has the same effect, so that's not a unique feature for let.

Comment: `using var has the same effect` no it does not. a top-level `var foo = 'bar';` adds a property `window.foo`. Another use of `let` over `var` is that multiple `let` declarations of the same variable will throw a `SyntaxError` rather than silently allowing them as `var` would when that's almost always an indication of a problem with the program. Last use is temporal dead zones, which follows from the fact that `let` has lexical scope while `var` does not. I'll let you read about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone).

Comment: lol that's very gracious of you but you're wrong and using let in the global scope is pointless. @patricroberts